# OpenCV Camhisft losing track around red object

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I am playing with the camshiftdemo.c [1] distributed with opencv. I select my face and it starts tracking but as soon as I move from my desk to a red couch, circle leaves my face and moves on the couch. Is there a way to change this behaviour?

[1] https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/c/camshiftdemo.c?rev=1429

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code from line 140, you can see that color is used to detect skin tones. This is a usual but oversimple way to do face detection. You can imagine that

1. such a method won't be able to detect all skin colors ;
2. objects whose color is closed to skin (like your red sofa) will interfere with detection.

You then have two options, either you use a method which is more robust on skin-color objects (with [shape-based face detection](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/c/facedetect.c?rev=1429) for example) or you don't use this one on your comfortable sofa :-)

Comment: Stephane, are referring to the inranges call with the values vmin smin I was under the impression that the selected regions histogram thus colors are used.